# Node.js - create HTML dropdown from JavaScript enum

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, enums, ejs

I am trying to create a dropdown menu based off an enum stored in my Node.js code (later on I will probably move the enum to the front-end).

the enum looks like this:

```
var SPORTS = {
    BASEBALL: {},
    ICE_HOCKEY: {},
    FIELD_HOCKEY: {},
    BASKETBALL: {},
    SOCCER: {},
    AMERICAN_FOOTBALL: {},
    RUGBY_UNION: {},
    RUGBY_LEAGUE: {},
    CRICKET: {},
    VOLLEYBALL: {},
    HANDBALL: {},
    CYCLING: {}
};

exports.SPORTS_ENUM = SPORTS;
```

this code is close, but it shows empty `<li>`s like so: `<li></li>`:

```
   <div class="dropdown">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <% for (var key in sportsEnum) {
            if (sportsEnum.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            %>
            <li><%= key %></li>
            <% }
            }%>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

but neither quite work, and I think it would be better to embed a script.
Assuming the style of the enum above is passable, what's the best way to create an html dropdown menu from that?

Comment: Yeah I am using EJS and Express

Comment: the view engine is set to EJS for anything that ends with .html

Comment: @icktoofay: Ah right it does, I shouldn't comment when I'm tired. Thanks for the correction. First snippet is JSTL though, which is for Java.